# The best suggestion for a structure to store multiple keys and values - dictionaries?

Tags: python, facebook, dictionary, structure, profile

The intention is to create the beginnings of a facebook type program (For teaching purposes) that stores a list of names of individuals along with their bio details.

I have two questions, one follows on from the next:

**Question 1**: How to get at the **list values** that are part of a value in a key value pair in a dictionary. For instance, to find out what friends John and Mary have in common, in this case **friend1 and friend3**

**Question 2:** The best method to create a structure that stores names,gender,hobbies,and friends? Would this be a dictionary and if so, how could this be defined? If not, what do people suggest?

```
#create a dictionary that stores names, and a list of friends
facebook_profile={"John":["friend1","friend2","friend3","friend4"],"Mary":["friend1","friend7","friend3","friend9"]}
print(facebook_profile)
```

**Required to store and subsequently print the following sample data:**

```
Name:John
Gender: Male
Hobbies: Chess
Friends: friend1,friend2,friend3,friend4

Name: Mary
Gender: Female
Hobbies: Chequers
Friends: friend1,friend2,friend3,friend4
```

I am aware the best solution would be a database and to use some sort of file handling to achieve it however, for teaching purposes we are trying to use only lists or dictionaries. These dictionaries/lists could then be written to a file, but the solution(s)/answers I am looking for must ideally be utilising only the list and dictionary structures.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to store in Database with table columns and firends having many-to-many relationship with that table.

Comment: Ah - no databases. As mentioned, this is for teaching purposes and the necessity is to use only list and dictionary based solutions (no files). Thanks however, for the suggestion

Comment: Ah problem with dict is you will have only one person with that name your facebook ;) . since dict don't allow duplicate keys.

Comment: Okay - that is the key - dictionary does not allow duplicate keys. So can a dictionary have a value that links to another object (like a list)

Answer (score 0):

For Question 1, a set is a good choice for quickly and easily calculating intersections. 
For Question 2, a dictionary works well.

For example:

```
facebook_profile={
    "John":{"friends":{"friend1","friend2","friend3","friend4"},"Gender": "Male"},
    "Mary":{"friends":{"friend1","friend7","friend3","friend9"},"Gender": "Female"}
}
mutual_friends = facebook_profile["John"]["friends"].intersection(facebook_profile["Mary"]["friends"])
print (mutual_friends)
```

Gives output:

```
{'friend1', 'friend3'}
```

Comment: Are you able to briefly explain, in this context, what the difference between a set and dictionary is in your answer to highlight why one is more useful over the other

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** You edited your answer to state you want lists and dicts only, So maybe this is not for you, however, classes are the best way to achieve complicated storage of information about similar repetitive objects with many features, so i'll just leave this here

As this gets more and more complicated, nested dictionaries can be a real headache, I would suggest you define a `class`, something like this:

```
class Person()
    def __init__(self, name, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender
```

For that class you can define all sorts of methods, like finding friends in common:

```
class Person()
    def __init__(self, name, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender
        self.friends = []
        self.hobbies = []
    def add_friends(self, list_of_friends):
        self.friends += list_of_friends
    def add_hobbies(self, list_of_hobbies):
        self.hobbies += list_of_hobbies
    def mutual_friends(self, another_person):
        return list(set(another_person.friends).intersection(self.friends))
```

Then all you have to do is initialize each friend and start running all sorts of methods

```
john = Person('John', 'Male')
john.add_friends(['friend1', 'friend2', ...]
mary = Person('Mary', 'Female')
mary.add_friends(['friend3', 'friend7', ...]
common_friends = john.mutual_friends(mary)
print(common_friends) # Will print a list of mutual friends
```

And like others said, for long lists of friends a more efficient way is to use `set` with `intersection`

Comment: I think students will find this very useful - a discussion on the best way forward (and this is question 2), so thank you -would it be possible to comment each line where appropriate as well (defining classes and what "self" is etc....(this would help a novice)

Answer (score 0):

Create a class:

```
class Person:

  def __init__(self, name, gender, hobbies, friends):
    self.name = name
    self.gender = gender
    self.hobbies = hobbies
    self.friends = friends

  def getMutualFriends(self, personB):
    return list(set(personB.friends).intersection(self.friends))

person1 = Person('John', 'male', ['Chess'], ['friend1', 'friend2'])
person2 = Person('Anna', 'female', ['Soccer'], ['friend1', 'friend3'])

print(person1.getMutualFriends(person2))
```